Excel subtract big numbers as hours and minutes
The subtracting 36716.09 from 28961.49 (36716.09 - 28961.49, ‘.’dot is separator represents minutes: 9 minutes and 49 respectively) yields 7754.60 Which accounts for 7755 hours.
However, the correct result is 7754.20, 7754 hours and 20 minutes.
36715 - 28961 =7754 hours
69 - 49 =20 minutes
I don’t have a particular preference to time format. The delimiter can be colon or any other separator as long as hours/minutes is one value, so can be allocated in one cell.
The values can be vary but do not exceed 7 digits, hhhhh.mm
I have tried different time/text functions/formulas and cell formats with no avail.
Could someone advise/point me on cause/solution of this error, please.
P.S.
Thank you all of stackoverflow community for the provided solutions.

 =(TRUNC(A1)/24+(A1-TRUNC(A1))/14.4)-(TRUNC(B1)/24+(B1-TRUNC(B1))/14.4)

Result custom formatted as [hh]:mm
Result:


Thank you @user11222393 for your prompt solution. It works perfectly. Can you elaborate/help me understand the formula logic. …/24 because excel treats hours greater than 23 as a fraction of and divide it /24. Right?

Basically Excel stores date and time as days passed since 1900 1 0. So 36716 for Excel is so much days or 881184 hours so you need to divide it by 24

I understand the logic but puzzled by 1.44. Why it is not 1440, which is supposed to be divider for minutes? And I have tried it just to see that 1440 yields the error.

I mean 14.4 ...

To convert 0.09 part to minutes is 0.09100/60/24, or 0.09100/1440 or 0.09/14.4

Don’t want to seem much inquisitive, but 24 is hours/day, 60*24=1440 is minutes/day, what is 100 ?

=LET(a, A1:A2, b, B1:B2, m_a, --RIGHT(a, 2), m_b, --RIGHT(b, 2),
(TRUNC(a) - TRUNC(b) - (m_a < m_b)) & ":" & ((m_a < m_b) * 60 + m_a - m_b))



Or converting to date time values, slightly different to user11222393's method, and setting to custom format [h]:mm:
=LET(
    input, A1:B2,
    hours, TRUNC(input),
    mins, --RIGHT(input, 2),
    date_time_values, TRUNC(hours / 24) + TIME(MOD(hours, 24), mins, 0),
    diff, INDEX(date_time_values, , 1) - INDEX(date_time_values, , 2),
    diff
)



Thank you @nkalvi for your effort to help, but this is a little bit complicated for my understanding/using.

You're most welcome. I'm glad that you found one that works for you.

Let assume that the two values are in cells A39 and B39
The formula converts the hours-minutes to a decimal number, does the subtraction (can apply any calculations with valx and valy in line  r,valx-valy,  and converts back to hours.minutes format.
With 365
=LET(valx,INT(A39)+(A39-INT(A39))*100/60,
valy,INT(B39)+(B39-INT(B39))*100/60,
r,valx-valy,
INT(r)+(r-INT(r))*0.6)

The formula in C39 gives the below result:




Col A
ColB
ColC




39
36716.09
28961.49
7754.2




Thank you @Black cat. it works perfectly and it doesn't need format cell, which is advantage.
